# c# Sorting array in Czech

Tags: c#, culture

I have problem sorting an array with Czech names. 
I have such array:

```
    var myList = new[]
    {
        "Čas revize", "Datum kalibrace", "Chybové kódy"
    };
```

and try to sort it like this:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
var result = myList.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Create(culture, true));
```

So I expect that the data will be sorted as follows:

```
"Čas revize", "Chybové kódy", "Datum kalibrace"
```

But it end it up in different order:

```
"Čas revize", "Datum kalibrace", "Chybové kódy"
```

Comment: The order is correct: `ch` is considered as a separate letter in the Czech alphabet instead of being a combination of `c` and `h`. It comes after `d`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question. If you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxc48dt(v=vs.110).aspx)

> In Czech - Czech Republic culture, "ch" is a single character that is greater than "d". However, in English - United States culture, "ch" consists of two characters, and "c" is less than "d".

The Czech alphabet is ordered

A   Á   B   C   Č   D   Ď   E   É   Ě   F   G   H   Ch  I   Í   J   K   L   M   N   Ň   O   Ó   P   Q   R   Ř   S   Š   T   Ť   U   Ú   Ů   V   W   X   Y   Ý   Z   Ž

So the ordering of your array is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "Čas revize", "Datum kalibrace", "Chybové kódy", "óóó", "ČČČ", "aaa", "ééé", "èèè", "êêê", "fff", "Code" };
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo ("cs-CZ");
List<string> result = myList.OrderBy (x => x, StringComparer.Create (culture, true)).ToList ();
```

And got the result:

> aaa Code 'Čas revize' ČČČ 'Datum kalibrace' ééé èèè êêê fff Chybové kódy óóó

Then I tested this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "Čas revize", "Datum kalibrace", "Chybové kódy", "óóó", "ČČČ", "aaa", "ééé", "èèè", "êêê", "fff", "Code" };
List<string> result = myList.OrderBy (j => j).ToList ();
```

And got this result:

> aaa 'Čas revize' ČČČ 'Chybové kódy' Code 'Datum kalibrace' ééé èèè êêê fff óóó

It is due to the fact that in the Czech language 'Ch' comes after 'H' and before 'I' in the alphabet. But without the CultureInfo, it seems to treat it correctly regardless of special characters.